# Do I need to pay the property tax under "Box 3" in the Netherlands if not renting out the apartment?

Tags: taxes, netherlands

I am considering buying an apartment in Amsterdam where I would stay for weekends while working in Switzerland during the week. I would not rent out the apartment nor reside in the Netherlands. Thus, would I need to pay the "Box 3" tax on property? Is it tax that you pay automatically as a property owner or you only need to pay it if you actually rent the apartment out? I am from a EU country.

Comment: Not sure about the exact rules regarding non-residents (hence a comment, not an answer) but the whole point of “box 3 inkomsten” is that it's a tax on property generally. It's not specific to real estate and it's not based on actual income but a on fictional income of 4% of the value of the property. In fact, even a vacation home abroad has to be declared as well. So it's difficult to see how an apartment that you are not renting out could be exempted.

Comment: Thinking about it, one question could be whether this apartment can be considered your main abode. You will spend more time in Switzerland but if your family lives in the Netherlands, most of your belongings are there, you don't own property in Switzerland, etc. you could still be a resident in the Netherlands. If that's the case, you would have to declare your worldwide income there (and possibly pay income taxes, depending on any tax treaty with Switzerland) but the apartment would not count for the purpose of “box 3 inkomsten” (just like a regular home).

Comment: Given all the potential complications, that's probably something you would need to take up with a tax advisor but it's an interesting question.

Comment: Gala, thank you for your comments! Referring to my situation, I don't have a family so I would be taxed in CH. I actually know a case when someone lives in the Netherlands with the family, travels there on weekends but rents an apartment in Switzerland and, hence, pays tax there (which comes with a benefit of a lower tax in the end).

Comment: I had a feeling it would be as you described with the 'box 3' that it's regardless of the actual income...